# Rails - How know if content is string or has been captured by capture_haml helper?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml

Sometimes I need to store inside a variable a content that is a single string, but sometimes I need a bigger content and I want to use `capture_haml` helper.

My question is, is there a way to know if the content of a variable has been captured by `capture_haml` helper? I need to do something specific in this case.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found a way by using a deboguer and by checking the type of the variable that contained a haml block using `myvar.instance_of? ActiveSupport::SafeBuffer`

```
- # The icon can be a font-awesome class or a haml/html content.
- # To use a block it must be captured through capture_haml helper.
- if local_assigns[:icon]
  - # Content captured using capture_haml is in a SafeBuffer instance.
  - if local_assigns[:icon].instance_of? ActiveSupport::SafeBuffer
    = icon
  - else
    - # Use font-awesome, expecting "icon" to contain only one or several classes.
    %i.fa{class: icon}
```